# Learning Java - importing and packages basics

Tags: java

I'm reading every tutorial I can find as well as a book, still trivial concetps leave me asking questions:

1. `CLASSPATH` is a variable registered with the JVM that tells java the root directory in which to start looking for classes/jars/etc?
2. `import` is similar to include (C/C++) but provides a namespace via package? I just read how without using import you have to explicitly state the package/namespace for every class (using the FQCN) such as java.util.String (possibly invalid excuse) where as using import java.util would allow me everywhere else in the code to simply refer to class as String.

What confuses me about import is some examples use import like:

```
import java.util.*;  // import all public classes from java.util package
import java.util.Hashtable;  // import only Hashtable class (not all classes in java.util   package)
```

Yes the article also follows up:

Note that we can call public classes stored in the package level we do the import only. We can't use any classes that belong to the subpackage of the package we import. For example, if we import package `world`, we can use only the `HelloWorld` class, but not the `HelloMoon` class.

So which is it, when I use the * in an import is that not recursively importing all sub-packages?

Comment: Correct--as the sentence states, you can't use any classes in subpackages, unless you explicitly import the subpackage (or subpackage class).

Comment: Classpath is a collection of locations and jars. Classes can only be found in jars explicitly included in the classpath in the command that launched the jvm. Files can be read at runtime from the classpath by including ".\" before file names.

Comment: Sub-packages are never recursively imported.

Answer (score 1):

[7.5.2. Type-Import-on-Demand Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html)

```
import java.util.*;
```

> **causes the simple names of all public types declared in the package java.util to be available within the class and interface declarations of the compilation unit**. Thus, the simple name Vector refers to the type Vector in the package java.util in all places in the compilation unit where that type declaration is not shadowed (§6.4.1) or obscured (§6.4.2).
>
> The declaration might be shadowed by a single-type-import declaration of a type whose simple name is Vector; by a type named Vector and declared in the package to which the compilation unit belongs; or any nested classes or interfaces.
>
> The declaration might be obscured by a declaration of a field, parameter, or local variable named Vector.
>
> (It would be unusual for any of these conditions to occur.)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Unlike C/C++ include, Java's import is optional, as Java loads all classes it finds in CLASSPATH regardless.

Java's import statements allows you to alias commonly used classes so you don't have to fully qualify them each time.

Let's say you have the following class defined:

```
package com.foo.bar;

public class Bazz {
    public static final int ONE = 1;
    public static final int TWO = 2;
    public static final int THREE = 3;

    ... some methods ...
}
```

There are several ways of using import:

```
import com.foo.bar.*;  // import all classes belonging to package com.foo.bar, and com.foo.bar only.
import com.foo.bar.Bazz;  // import class com.foo.bar.Bazz only
import static com.foo.bar.Bazz.*;  // import all static constants in class com.foo.bar.Bazz
import static com.foo.bar.Bazz.ONE;  // import static constant com.foo.bar.Bazz.ONE only
```

As you state, there is no way of recursively importing packages.

As an aside, most IDEs will auto-import the classes for you.  For example, Eclipse does this when you press CTRL+SHIFT+O.

Answer (score 0):

As in the example you provided in the question, when you specify

```
import java.util.*;
```

You import all of the public classes in the java.util package.  You do not import any public classes that reside outside the java.util package.

Integrated development environments (IDE) like Eclipse will create individual class imports for you.  There's not much reason to code a global import (with an asterisk) any more.

Comment: Yes.  if you feel that way, just type import java.* and be done with language imports.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's what it does. 

 But it is best practice to provide absolute path in the `import` statement.